# Re-Enabling a disabled user active directory

Tags: active-directory

We have an active directory domain controller configured and within this there is a current user directory and a Disabled user directory. We have a user who was previously with the company and has now come back but when I reenable the account in active directory and then move to the current user directory the login details are still being read as being disabled.

Are there any other further configuration required in order to reenable a user in active directory or could this be a a case of the changes not being yet applied?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/422127/clear-active-directory-cache-from-user-machine

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have unchecked 'Account is disabled'. Also make sure there is no expiry date on the account (or the expiry date is in the future).

Did anyone set logon restrictions on the account too? (in AD Users and Computers, that's the 'Logon Hours' and 'Log On To' buttons on the Account tab)

It's also possible the changes hadn't replicated when you first tried.